# Finding the most similar index in an array using Euclidian distance

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy, euclidean-distance

so I have an array and given a certain row, I want to output the most similar row using Euclidean distanceing? I know its in scipy.spatial.distance but I can't figure out how to implement it!

so e.g:

```
S = np.array([[1, 10, 2, 5, 1],
              [10, 3, 1, 3, 3],
              [2, 2, 9, 8, 5],
              [9, 5, 4, 1, 4],
              [8, 7, 5, 5, 3],
              [7, 2, 9, 9, 8]])

row = [7, 2, 9, 9, 8]
```

would output that the most similar row is 5

TIA!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it really fast (without the slow `for` loop hidden inside comprehension lists) by using numpy's [`linalg.norm`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.norm.html) function with an `axis=1` argument :

```
row_id = np.argmin(np.linalg.norm(S-row, axis=1))

print(S[row_id]) # Returns array([7, 2, 9, 9, 8])
```